# NTM on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, gnome, monitor, traffic

I have just installed NTM - Network Traffic Monitor on my Ubuntu. I've set the wlp3s0 interface, the one that i've seen running ifconfig. But application has just crashed and now, running NTM from terminal, the error is

```
 Vector smash protection is enabled.
 NOT SANDBOXED
```

How can i fix this error? I've already tried to uninstall and reinstall the app.

Thank you.

Comment: I have just tested it in my Xubuntu 16.04, it works fine. Could you tell which version did you install,1.3.1 ?